# Delphi XE2: Rect ambiguity?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rect

The **Rect** function is declared in two units:

System.Classes.Rect
System.Types.Rect

Why this ambiguity? Is one of these functions deprecated? Which one should be preferred?

Comment: Do they have the identical parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation, `System.Types.Rect` takes integer values for the four corners of the rectangle; `System.Classes.Rect` on the other hand also provides an overload that takes two `TPoint`s - one for top-left, one for bottom right.  Both return a `TRect` so it's really a matter of choice which you use.

The latter is more flexible (offering two overloads) so it's probably best to make sure you include `Classes` after `Types` in your uses clause (if using both) to not hide the more versatile method provided by `Classes`.

Comment: Or just correctly clarify which one you mean to use in your code by declaring the variable as `var R: Classes.Rect` or `var R: Types.Rect`, so there's no ambiguity later on if the uses clause gets altered. :-) I'm also not sure I'd use "powerful" to describe the difference; maybe "more flexible" would be a better choice?

Comment: @KenWhite - these are functions, not types... it would be `var R : TRect` in either case, assigned as `R := Classes.Rect(args)` or `R:=Types.Rect(args)`.  Or is it just too late and I'm scrambled?  You probably wouldn't do it this way in any case since the purpose of these functions is to skirt around the local variable when assigning a `TRect` property of some other class.  Point was that if you're using `Rect` with `TPoint` args then declaring `Types` after `Classes` will hide the overload that makes it work.  I guess you could always use `Classes.Rect(args)` to guard against that.

Comment: Sorry. You're right; I misread the question. :-) My comment still applies, though; if you have unit ambiguity that depends on the order in the uses clause and you can avoid that by clearly referencing which one you mean, it's usually better to do so. So `R := Classes.Rect(args);` would work too, and it makes it clear that you're referring to the specific function(s) from the `Classes` unit. But it probably isn't as important here, as long as the compiler can tell which one you meant. :-) I still think I'd use "more flexible", but that's just being picky. :D

Comment: @KenWhite - fair enough - 'more flexible' is better.  Being picky just means caring about semantics, and in this business that's the whole point, isn't it? ;)  Agreed also that getting rid of ambiguity is the best solution.  Good points.

Answer (score 3):

If you're to call `Rect` in a tight loop (which doesn't do I/O or similar), consider calling `types.Rect`, which is what `classes.Rect` really does; it calls `types.Rect` (but then you may need to inline your own Rect...). Otherwise it doesn't matter, I wouldn't bother including 'types' in 'uses' just to save one level of indirection.

Comment: Aye, deleted my comment after you added the bit about inlining...I guess what I meant was that if performance was a consideration then the choice wouldn't be between `Types.Rect` and `Classes.Rect` - if assembling a Rect is a bottleneck then, as you say, there are better options than either.